# Javascript - How to trucate string and add three dots at end

Tags: javascript

I have a js string and I wanted to truncate it after 43 char and add three dots (...) at end. Three dots can be em dash.

Now the problem is if there was a whitespace at the end with truncated string I wanted to disallow it. Like, the funcation will skipp whitespace at the end while char count and add three dots.

```
getTruncatedName = (source) => {
         let skippedString = source.trimEnd();
         if(skippedString.length > 43){
             return skippedString.substring(0, 43) + '...';
         }else{
             return source;
         }
     }
```

Diamond and Mother-of-pearl Circle Pendant in gold plate

Output:

```
Diamond and Mother-of-pearl Circle Pendant ...
```

I want :

```
Diamond and Mother-of-pearl Circle Pendant...
```

If i count before ... its 42 but i want 43

Comment: if this is for display somewhere on a page, just use css.

Comment: Nope I need it through js only

Comment: It is simple if you use CSS. Is there any specific reason for doing this in JavaScript? I am just curious to know

Comment: I need char count badly throuh js only

Comment: The output you want can be achieved by using `trim()` which trims the white space from both ends of a string. You can do that before you append the `...`. But I'm not sure I understand your very last statement: *If i count before ... its 42 but i want 43* Er, yeah the 43rd character is the space, which is trimmed in that example.

Answer (score 2):

Does it always put a space there? Or could it be that there is a space at the 43th position and thus that is part of the string and included.

So maybe try re-trimming again. Like such

return skippedString.substring(0, 43).trimEnd() + '...';

Comment: No. Its based on how data are comming from backend apis. Yes in this case there was a space at 43th pos.

Comment: @DanielSmith This seems to be the correct answer. `trimEnd()` will drop the whitespace if it's present and won't change anything if it's not.

Comment: @DanielSmith this should work.  What solution did you end up doing if not?